# What to do if I stole something but I am too selfish and scared to return it

Tags: money, parents, forgiveness

So 6 month ago I stole 335$ from my parent because I wanted a phone but after I realized that I needed more and I couldn’t get it cause my parent were home so then it got me thinking and I immediately realized what I have done and I want forgiveness but I don’t khow it says to return it but I want to keep it and I want to give it back but I don’t khow how cause I’m scared that they will hit me

Comment: Then correct your selfishness and fear and return it. We are not a support group.

Comment: How did you manage to steal so much money  ? [] Don't your parents know that the money is missing  ?

Answer (score 0):

Assalam u alykum brother or sister If you have stolen money from your mother and father then seek forgivness from allah because stealing is a major sin in islam so give back the money for the sake of allah and apoligize for the money you stole thet they worked for to provied for you and wallahi allah will reward you I know you really want to get a phone but my sister or brother the hereafter is better than this world and im not telling you dont get a phone because allah does say we have portion in this world but brother or sister be truthful to your mother mother and father beccause allah said that being truthfull leads to being  righteous and being righteous enters enter you into jannah so my brother or sister please give back the money there is a very sad story of a person who died and owed someone money and a man came and said i will pay money to the person who he forget to pay I.e the dead person. he didnt pay this money to the person for quite a while so when he final paid prophet muhammed (SAW) said the punishment for the debt he was facing  was just stopped. so brother or sister I dont want you to be like him  be truthful and give back the money and allah will forgive you inshallah and notify me if it went well. and nexttime ask your parents for money we all make mistakes but what we need to do is correct them jazakallah assalm u alykum warhmutulahi wabrakatu.